# Python Get complete string before last slash

Tags: python

I want to get complete string path before last occurrence of slash (/)

```
String : /d/d1/Projects/Alpha/tests
Output : /d/d1/Projects/Alpha
```

I am able to get the last part of string after last slash by doing

```
String.split('/')[-1]
```

But I want to get `"/d/d1/Projects/Alpha"`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest option is `str.rpartition`, which will give you a 3-tuple of the string before, including, and after the rightmost occurrence of a given separator:

```
>>> String = "/d/d1/Projects/Alpha/tests"
>>> String.rpartition("/")[0]
'/d/d1/Projects/Alpha'
```

For the specific case of finding the directory name given a file path (which is what this looks like), you might also like `os.path.dirname`:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.dirname(String)
'/d/d1/Projects/Alpha'
```

Comment: `os.path.dirname` is the way to go as it is platform agnostic

Comment: @Samwise : One litte tweak if I want to replace the last part with some other string , how it can be done in above , like output should be '/d/d1/Projects/Alpha/workspace' , here test was replaced with workspace ?

Comment: @DeepSpace I agree that give a file path `dirname` is the best way to get the directory name, but OP asked about strings in general and gave a file path as an example, which is different from asking about file paths.  :)  It might be that this isn't actually a local file path, in which case `os.path` might not do the right thing.

Comment: @Bokambo Could do `String.rpartition("/")[0] + "/workspace"` -- or again, if we're allowed to assume that this is a local file path, do `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(String), "workspace")`

Answer (score 2):

Use `str.rfind` function:

```
s = '/d/d1/Projects/Alpha/tests'
print(s[:s.rfind('/')])
```

---

```
/d/d1/Projects/Alpha
```

Answer (score 2):

Two easy methods:
**Using split**
as you did, you can use `split` method, then use `join`, as following, it should work:

```
in_str = "/d/d1/Projects/Alpha/tests"
out_str = '/'.join(in_str.split('/')[:-1]) # Joining all elements except the last one
```

Or
**Using os.path.dirname** (would recommend, cleaner)

```
in_str = "/d/d1/Projects/Alpha/tests"
out_str = os.path.dirname(in_str)
```

Both give the awaited result